# Eclipse and APK and BAR

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry, apk

Can I convert an APK to BAR in Eclipse and edit the format for blackberry but still maintain the original APK for Android?
In other words I have one app that I want in two different formats. One for Google Play and One for Blackberry App World but I want to be able to edit them separately for the sake of format but keep the same for functionality.
It is a simple text app but the formats and are different for each.
Thank you.
Sorry I had a hard time explaining what I need.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot convert Android APK apps into the Blackberry BAR format. However, I heard there is some kind of runtime for BB that allows you to run Android apps. I wouldn't recommend doing that though.

Comment: actually Eclipse does the conversion after you install the Blackberry plugin. I am looking at it. After you verify it and then sign it to app world, it gets saved as a bar file. (in blackberry tools)I just wanted to be able to basically have two versions so I could actively edit the functionality once.

Comment: Oh thats actually really cool then! You learn something new every day :) (In my case, me)